# disable and enable input when a radio is selected in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I have a radio button that I want to enable an item when selected.  How do I enable the text input when a certain radio is selected like the first one or the last radio?

```
<div>
  <div data-bind="foreach: radios">
    <label>Radio</label><input type="radio" name="radios"
    data-bind="text: Text, value: Value, checked: $parent.radios()[0].Value" />
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input name="enableSomeText" type="text" name="enable_me" data-bind="enable: $parent.radios().SelectedValue" />
</div>
```

In the model view the radios is an observable array containing the text criteria and which radio button is enabled by default.  [{"Text": "Rad1", "Value": "Winter"}, {Text": "Rad2", "Value": "Summer"}, ... ]

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to assign checked to an observable and then use that to control the text box:

```
<div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: radios">
        <label data-bind="text: Text"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="radios" data-bind="value: Value, checked: $root.selectedRadio" />
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <input name="enableSomeText" type="text" name="enable_me" data-bind="enable: selectedRadio() == 'Summer'"/>
</div>

var model = {
    selectedRadio: ko.observable(""),
    radios: ko.observableArray([{
        "Text": "Rad1",
            "Value": "Winter"
    }, {
        "Text": "Rad2",
            "Value": "Summer"
    }, {
        "Text": "Rad3",
            "Value": "Fall"
    }])
};
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Comment: The first radio can be a season but I don't know the order.  I just know I need the first one.  Is there a way to select based on inner text or on the order?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to enable the text box if the first radio is selected? Only the first radio? Or any of the radios? If it is the first just change the selectedRadio() == 'Summer' to selectedRadio() == radios()[0].Value. If it is ANY radio just change it to selectedRadio() != ''

Comment: Unfortunately there was an issue with a third party control that was causing most of the problems.

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve desired behavior by binding $index instead of value. You also can add computed observable to your model to get actual value from array you used for binding, so you will have both index and value in your viewmodel.

```js
ko.extenders.position = function(target, index) {
  target.position = ko.observable(ko.unwrap(index));
  return target;
}

var model = {
  selectedRadioIndex: ko.observable(0),
  radios: ko.observableArray([{
    "Text": "Rad1",
    "Value": "Winter"
  }, {
    "Text": "Rad2",
    "Value": "Summer"
  }, {
    "Text": "Rad3",
    "Value": "Fall"
  }])
};

model.selectedRadio = ko.computed(function() {
  return model.radios()[model.selectedRadioIndex()].Value;
});
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div data-bind="foreach: radios">
    <label data-bind="text: Text"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="radios" data-bind="checkedValue: $index, checked: $root.selectedRadioIndex" />
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input name="val" type="text" name="enable_me" data-bind="enable: selectedRadioIndex() == 0" />
</div>

<div>
  --- Selected Index: <span data-bind="text: selectedRadioIndex"></span>
</div>
<div>
  --- Selected Value: <span data-bind="text: selectedRadio"></span>
</div>
```